# What is the VB.NET equivalent of List<?> in Java

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'm strictly looking for a language conversion here of this:

```
List<?>
```

I already have a work around I'm just surprised that I can't find the vb.net equivalent of a variable type of a "raw" generic list that takes a wild card.
Java's mechanism here enables you to reference a list regardless of what T is.
Java even enables you to go further and do things like:

```
List<? extends Number>
List<? super Double>
```

I tried:

```
List(Of )
```

and that did not work. That only seems to work inside the GetType function.

Comment: try looking on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Y0

Comment: C# doesn’t have wildcards last I looked – do you mean Java?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, there is no special `?` place holder in c# or VB. No?

Comment: Right. I just found out this is from Java, not C#. My bad.

Comment: I updated my ? to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Generic Types in Visual Basic (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w256ka79%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN. What you're looking for is called a Type Constraint. You'll have to combine that with a declaration on a method or class that performs the restriction that you want.

To accept any type you can do:

```
Public Sub testSub(Of t)(arg As List(Of t))
    'Do something.
End Sub
```

Or to restrict it, for example, to a value type, you can do:

```
Public Sub testSub(Of t As Structure)(arg As List(Of t))
    'Do something.
End Sub
```

What you're looking for is a purely generic property which isn't allowed in the .Net Framework. The code below will not compile.

```
Public Property testSub(Of t) As List(Of t)
    Get
    End Get
    Set
    End Set
End Property
```

The closest you can get is:

```
Public Class testClass(Of T)
    Public Property testSub As List(Of t)
        Get
        End Get
        Set
        End Set
    End Property 
End Class
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried: Dim MyListVar As MyList(Of T as MyBaseObject) and that did not compile. Intellisense didn't give the "As" keyword after T.

Comment: Ok we are getting closer! My reference is actually a property. I'm ok with it is the property has to take an argument. Is there a way to declare a property thusly?

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't C# generics declarations, they're Java declarations, so there is no equivalent in VB.NET.

As Konrad states in his comment above, Java and C# have quite different generic implementations. C# works by expansion, Java by erasure. Thus in C# there is no "raw" generic type available.

Comment: Ok. Phooey. No wonder I couldn't find it. Something to look forward to in the next version I suppose! Thanks!

Comment: @toddmo No, it won't be in the next version. The ECMA specification has an explicit clause preventing this from being done. It's a core part of the generics approach in C#.

Comment: Wow! I have to declare my variable "As IList". That seems less than optimal for type safety and intellisense. Oh well...

Comment: @toddmo - that's not an equivalent, that's rather a non-generic base interface that `IList<T>` extends. You've erased the type yourself effectively... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about

```
List(of T)
List(of String)
```

etc.

Comment: No, because I'm not inside a generic class when I'm declaring this type. I simply want a variable of the raw generic type. If I put List(of T) in there it won't compile.

Comment: @toddmo .NET has no concept of generic type erasure and hence no raw generic types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my goal was to be able have a Collection property on MyBaseClass that points to it's collection, which is of type MyCollection(Of T), where T is a type of MyBaseClass. The base class does not know what will subclass it. It therefore needed to assign any implementation of MyCollection AND get the early binding and intellisense.

I needed to have my cake and eat it too (early binding and late binding).

Here's what I did inside MyBaseClass:

```
  Public Event pCollectionChanged(Value As IList)
  Private _pCollection As IList
  <XmlIgnore()> _
  <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)> _
  Public Property pCollection As IList
    Get
      Return _pCollection
    End Get
    Set(Value As IList)
      If _pCollection Is Value Then Exit Property
      _pCollection = Value
      RaiseEvent pCollectionChanged(Value)
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Function Collection(Of t As MyBaseClass)() As MyCollection(Of t)
    Return pCollection
  End Function
```

Now I can assign a MyCollection(Of anything) to pCollection, and I can do this from calling code:

```
Dim MyObject As New MyBaseClassSubType    
MyObject.Collection(Of MyBaseClassSubType).MyNeatoCollectionMethod
```

whereas before I just had Collection As IList, which did not give me access to MyNeatoCollectionMethod

Tada! Thanks to all those who answered.